# Import contacts missing button

Tags: wordpress, civicrm.settings.php, php7

Under Contacts --> Import contacts the button is missing to select which type of contacts should be imported as csv.[it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSy2L.jpg)[image: Unfortunately, this is what it looks like]

Comment: That is how I see it on demo site at http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/import/contact?reset=1 so you may need to add more info about your set up

Comment: My setup is wordpress 4.9.4, php 7.0, civicrm 4.7.31.